# Find equation of Tangent line at $(4, 1)$ on $5y^3 + x^2 = y + 5x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me find equation of tangent line at $(4, 1)$ on
 $5y^3 + x^2 = y + 5x$
$Y=f(x)$

I dont know how to isolate the $Y$

Comment: Welcome to SE! Can you show us your attempt? That would help us to help you.

Comment: Don't isolate $y$, use implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

knowing

$$
y-y_0 = y'(x-x_0)
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}[3y^3+x^2] = \frac{d}{dx}[y+5x]
$$

$$
15y^2 y' + 2x = y' + 5
$$

$$
2x-5 = y'[1-15y^2] \therefore
$$

$$
y' = \frac{2x-5}{1-15y^2}
$$

When at the point (4,1) you get

$$
y-1 = \frac{2(4)-5}{1-15}(x-4)
$$

$$
y = \frac{12-3x}{14}+1 = \frac{13}{7}-\frac{3x}{14}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much Eric! Yeah i tried implicit differentiation but was lost after that. But thanks again i understand it know :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}5y^3 + x^2 = y + 5x$$
$$=y'15y^2 + 2x = y' + 5$$
$$=y'15y^2-y' = -2x + 5$$
$$=y'(15y^2-1) = -2x + 5$$
$$=y' = \dfrac{-2x + 5}{(15y^2-1)}$$
Plugging in the point $(4,1)$ gives

$$y'=-\dfrac{3}{14}$$